# Laravel - Query scope in another model doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There is a model named `Message` as follow (the `user_id` is sender of the message):

```
class Message extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'visible', 'message_type_id', 'user_id'];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Modules\User\Entities\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function user_messages() // recipients
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Modules\Message\Entities\MessageUser', 'message_id');
    }

    public function scopeReceiver($query, $user_id)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('user_messages', function($q) use ($user_id){
            $q->receiver($user_id);
        });
    }

    public function scopeUnread($query)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('user_messages', function ($q){
            $q->unread();
        });
    }

    public function scopeAuthor($query, $user_id)
    {
        return $query->where("user_id", $user_id);
    }
```

Since a message maybe sent to multiple users, I created a model named `MessageUser` which contains list of recipients of every message. it is as follows (the `read` column is boolean):

```
class MessageUser extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['message_id', 'user_id', 'read'];
    protected $table = "message_user";

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Modules\User\Entities\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function scopeReceiver($query, $user_id)
    {
        return $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
    }

    public function scopeUnread($query)
    {
        return $query->where('read', 0);
    }

    public function scopeTheMessage($query, $message_id)
    {
        return $query->where('message_id', $message_id);
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Modules\Message\Entities\Message', 'message_id');
    }
}
```

I need to get the unread messages sent from a specific user to the current user. This is the code I wrote which is not working

```
public function unreadMessages($user_id)
{
    $author = $user_id;
    $recipient = $this->user->id;
    dd(Message::author($author)->receiver($recipient)->unread()->get());
    $count = Message::author($author)->receiver($recipient)->unread()->count();
    return $count;
}
```

The result of `dd` is wrong. It successfully returns messages written by an author to current user, but it has problem with unread messages. Here is the problem:

[image]

the current user id is `2`, and rows shown in rectangle are messages sent by a user to current user. The query

```
Message::author($author)->receiver($recipient)->get();
```

returns `4` shown messages which is right, but the query

```
Message::author($author)->receiver($recipient)->unread()->get();
```

return records with id `6, 17`. The record with id `17` is right cause it is actually unread but record with id `6` is wrong. From what I observed I findout that it returns the wrong result because record with id `7` is unread! `message_id` 28 in records `6,7,8` is sent to three users. Because there is at least one user who didn't read it, so always returns that message as unread, no matter who the recipient is.

Comment: I think It's because you can't call the scope `unread` from `MessageUser` in the `whereHas` closure from the function `scopeUnread` in your `Message` class.
Because the model assigned to the query builder is currently `Message`, not `MessageUser` so the condition is not added.
Can you try with the entiere condition ?

Comment: @JulienMetral thanks to your reply, but I can call the scope `receiver` which actually belongs to `MessageUser` and it works

Comment: What did you get with `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` ? ([usage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging))